Localization of Modules and Rings
For a ring $R$ and any non-nilpotent element $x$, we can consider the localization of $R$ by $\{1, x, x^2, \dots\}$. We can write this as $R_x$. Suppose $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $I = (2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$. We can see that $I$ is not a free module of rank 1 over $R$, but how can we show that $I_2$ is a free module of rank $1$ over $R_2$, and $I_3$ is a free module of rank $1$ over $R_3$? I think the idea is to try to find a basis for $I_2$ and $I_3$, but not sure how to determine what a basis should be.

Hint: Simplify $I_2$.
